# Выделение PyQt5 QIcon как ошибка в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pycharm

Почему возникает ошибка (выделение что это ошибка) в PyCharm. И как ее исправить.

> Cannot find refence 'QIcon' in 'QtGui.pyd'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**

Если вместо  `from PyQt5 import QtGui` вводить `from PyQt5.QtGui import *` то: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вводить `from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon` то:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE РАЗРЯДНОСТЬ**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ошибки в `Spyder`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что в `QtGui.pyd` PyCharm не нашел объект. Попробуйте `from PyQt5.QtGui import *` / `from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon`

Comment: @gil9red обновил вопрос. Не совсем понимаю почему именно с `QIcon` такая проблема потому что в любом случае она работает корректно, но как ошибка выделяется и пишет мол в некоторых случаях данная строка может не работать.

Comment: У меня при любом варианте показывает что объект найден. Какая версия PyCharm?

Comment: @gil9red PyCharm 2017.3 (Community Edition)

Comment: @Дмитрий питон вам ошибки выдает?

Comment: @Gleb нет не выдает ошибку( подчеркивание) выдает  `PyCharm` и `Visual Studio` в обоих случаях одна ошибка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная ошибка, как правило, связанна с тем, что статический анализатор кода настроен на использование описаний к PyQt4

Если данная ошибка влияет на работоспособность программы:

можно предположить, что у Вас установлено несколько интерпретаторов питона. Например в системе есть, кроме стандартного, еще анаконда, либо применяли virtualenv.

Проверить какой интерпретатор задействован в PyCharm:
file -> settings -> project "name" -> project interpreter

В консоли (линукс) qmake -v покажет какая версия будет использована по умолчанию.

если версии совпадают - попробуйте сменить и вернуть обратно используемый интерпретатор в PyCharm и\или проверить разрядность установленных интерпретаторов и переустановить pyqt(или как раз задействовать virtualenv).

Если ошибка не влияет на работоспособность кода, но раздражает:

1) принудительно проинспектировать проект (code - inspect code)  и добавить данные ошибки в игнорируемые.

2) настроить pycodestyle (file-settings - "project name" interpreter - найти в списке pycodestyle и дважды по нему кликнуть) на игнорирование такого типа ошибок в принципе, думаю не совсем хорошо в долгосрочной перспективе

в Spyder можно просто добавить в начало файла

```
# pylint: disable=missing-docstring 
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module 
# pylint: disable=unused-import
```

Comment: Не совсем понял ответ конечно, но после переустановки самого `python` и `PyQt5` ничего не изменилось кроме того что у меня теперь все команды связанные с `QtGui` выделяются как `QIcon`

Comment: куда ссылается qmake -v и куда интерпретатор в PyCharm?

Comment: у меня не линукс а в PyCharm ссылается на нужный интерпретатор python

Comment: вопрос не в том, нужный или нет, а в том - одинаковый ли :) qmake в командной строке не работает?

Comment: Нет не работает

Comment: обидно, у меня windows нет. pyqt ставили через pip и не ставили ли в систему анаконду?

Comment: когда то давно ставил но удалял ее уже

Comment: 2 варианта вижу 1)поставить обратно анаконду, соответственно самую свежую версию 2) поставить virtualenv, в виртуальное окружение заново поставить pyqt и в pycharm прописать его же

Comment: Все варианты которые были перечислены попробовал все так же как и было осталось

Comment: у Вас данная ошибка возникает в pycharm какой разрядности?
 или в обоих? дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос разрядностью питона и pycharm которые используете(смотреть в свойствах ярлыка для pycharm и в командной строке для питона) и скрином интерпретатора в pycharm

Comment: 64 разрядный обновил вопрос

Comment: не хватает интерпретатора проекта, кстати в анаконде есть встроенный ide spyder - там ошибка воспроизводится?

Comment: не пробовал чуть позже проверю, подредактировал это то что вам нужно?

Comment: Попробовал в ide spyder там такого нету, но там как такового поддержки pep8 нету ну или я не понимаю как его подключить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70140/discussion-between--and-stefan-bloodhawk).